# Tor node additional flags configuration

Tags: configuration, anonymity, relays, help, network-configuration

I recently stumbled upon these new additional flags in the Tor Metrics website:

[image: additional flags]

I’d like to configure my tor node to also have the FallbackDir and IPv6 ORPort flags, but don’t know what to add or modify in the /etc/tor/torrc file and how to configure it.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fallback Directories**

Fallback directory mirrors are hard-coded into Tor. You need to have a fast, stable relay with the same IP (v4 and v6) for at least 1-2 years to be considered. More information about fallback directories here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/FallbackDirectoryMirrors

Once or twice a year, a script chooses 150-200 relays from the potential list to be added to the official list. ([source](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/UpdatingFallbackDirectoryMirrors))

If your relay qualifies, send a message to the tor-relays mailing list and ask to have your relay added: https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-relays

You need to set `ContactInfo` in `torrc`.

**IPv6 ORPort**

To get an IPv6 ORPort, your relay needs to have an IPv6 connection and a configured IPv6 ORPort. You can find your IPv6 address using `ifconfig` or similar commands.

Once you have your IPv6 address, specify an IPv6 ORPort in your `torrc`:

```
ORPort [2001:DB8::1]:9050
```

Obviously, use your own IPv6 address and your preferred port. More information about IPv6 relays can be found here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/IPv6RelayHowto

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for such a quick and well explained reply! :)